# is giving username and password on phpmailer is safe?

Tags: php, security, passwords, phpmailer

My question is that,is using our real username and password on phpmailer for sending message,is safe to use?,anyone can steel our username and password,from my php script.is any solution is there,except hiding view source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs and passwords for email are much the same as IDs and passwords for database connections. Generally speaking, nobody other than you (and other sysadmins on the same server) should be able to see your source code, nor these passwords. PHP code is not visible to people visiting your site (unless you have misconfigured your server).

That doesn't mean you should not take precautions; There are ways of making this information available to your application without leaving it in source files, for example by putting them into `.env` files which are loaded into your environment (using something like [Env](https://github.com/m1/Env)), but are not actually part of your code base.

This allows you to keep passwords out of git repos, and should be stored outside your web root.

Furthermore, these files [can be encrypted](https://github.com/psecio/secure_dotenv), but that really just moves the problem further along because at some point you'll need to store the key to decrypt it with.

Comment: but sir when my website given on live server,than anyone can click view source code,and can see my password or username on contact us form?, is .env is work on simple php code?

Comment: No, they can’t see your PHP code. They can see HTML, JavaScript, CSS, but not PHP. They can see the *output* from your PHP, but not the source code.